# cProfile shows significant tottime in function which only exclusively calls an external Cython function

Tags: python, numpy, cython, cprofile

I have a function that calls a function from a compiled Cython library `multiply_vec` as follows:

```
def ScorePair(self):
    return multiply_vec.multiply_v2(self.x,self.y)
```

When running cProfile I get the following output:

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
5584965   19.437    0.000   19.437    0.000 {multiply_vec.multiply_v2}
5584965   13.567    0.000   33.005    0.000 model.py:235(ScorePair)
```

I am wondering why tottime is 13.7 seconds for ScorePair - should it not be close to zero? Or are there some hidden overheads which contribute to tottime?

My guess is that perhaps the conversion from the output of the function to a Python (Numpy) type may be causing this overhead, but I'm not sure. Just wondering if anyone could shed some light on this, or knows the source of the overhead. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't sound too unreasonable for Python. You're making 5.5 million calls, and Python has a lot of overhead, plus the extra from the profiler. You may need to shove more work into the C part.

Comment: That's still only about 2.4 microseconds per call. Some of that overhead will come from attribute lookups and from the function call itself.